# Make JS-function with if/else mongodb-update shorter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to make this function a little bit shorter? I don't like the if/else update, which is nearly the same. The only difference is the `'status.edited': false` which should only be set, if method = reset. Otherwise it shouldn't be modified.

```
function updateVersion(id, method) {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

    if (method == 'reset') {
        Collection.update(
            { _id: id }, 
            { 
                $set:   { 'status.version': timestamp, 'status.edited': false },
                $unset: { 'status.editing': '' }
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        Collection.update(
            { _id: id },
            { 
                $set:   { 'status.version': timestamp },
                $unset: { 'status.editing': '' }
            }
        );      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your query dynamically like this:

```
function updateVersion(id, method) {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var update = { 
        '$set': { 'status.version': timestamp },
        '$unset': { 'status.editing': '' } 
    };

    if (method === 'reset')
        update['$set']['status.edited'] = false;

    Collection.update( { '_id': id }, update );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object for dynamic properties and pass this to the query.

```
var set = {
    'status.version': timestamp
};

if(method === 'reset') {
    set['status.edited'] = false;
}

Collection.update({
    _id: id
}, {
    $set: set,
    $unset: {
        'status.editing': ''
    }
});
```